# Filter Object out of Array with difference of matching two values

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array, which I want to filter with another array. My goal is to filter the array with two values and I want the result with only matching exactly this two values. This is what I have so far:

```
const array = [
  {
    title: 'Title A',
    someOtherProps: [
      'AAA',
    ]
  }, {
    title: 'Title B',
    someOtherProps: [
      'AAA',
      'BBB',
    ]
  }, {
    title: 'Title C',
    someOtherProps: [
      'BBB',
      'CCC'
    ]
  }, {
    title: 'Title D',
    someOtherProps: [
      'BBB',
    ]
  }, {
    title: 'Title E',
    someOtherProps: [
      'CCC'
    ]
  },
]

const filter = [
  'AAA',
  'BBB',
]

let result = array.filter(obj => obj.someOtherProps.some(props => filter.includes(props)))
console.log(result);
```

So my result has Objects with my filtered value.

```
// My Result
{
  title: 'Title A'
  someOtherProps: [
    'AAA',
  ]
}, {
  title: 'Title B'
  someOtherProps: [
    'AAA',
    'BBB',
  ]
}, {
  title: 'Title C'
  someOtherProps: [
    'BBB',
    'CCC'
  ]
}, {
  title: 'Title D'
  someOtherProps: [
    'BBB',
  ]
}
```

So far so good. But I dont need all objects, which has one of the values. I need the object, which has exactly these two values combined.

```
// Wanted Result
{
  title: 'Title B'
  someOtherProps: [
    'AAA',
    'BBB',
  ]
}
```

I cant find a way. I know how to get the difference of two arrays. But I need the difference of two values, if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array#every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) on `filter` array and check its all values are included in the `someOtherProps` of object.
You can use [`Array#find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for that purpose if you want only one object

```js
const array = [ { title: 'Title A', someOtherProps: [ 'AAA', ] }, { title: 'Title B', someOtherProps: [ 'AAA', 'BBB', ] }, { title: 'Title C', someOtherProps: [ 'BBB', 'CCC' ] }, { title: 'Title D', someOtherProps: [ 'BBB', ] }, { title: 'Title E', someOtherProps: [ 'CCC' ] }, ]

const filter = ['AAA','BBB',]

let res = array.find(x => filter.every( a => x.someOtherProps.includes(a)));
console.log(res)
```

If you want all the elements that matches the condition then use `filter()`.

```js
const array = [ { title: 'Title A', someOtherProps: [ 'AAA', ] }, { title: 'Title B', someOtherProps: [ 'AAA', 'BBB', ] }, { title: 'Title C', someOtherProps: [ 'BBB', 'CCC' ] }, { title: 'Title D', someOtherProps: [ 'BBB', ] }, { title: 'Title E', someOtherProps: [ 'CCC' ] }, ]

const filter = ['AAA','BBB',]

let res = array.filter(x => filter.every( a => x.someOtherProps.includes(a)));
console.log(res)
```

Comment: yo, nice one. Thank you very very much :D I get it. didnt think about `every` this way!

Comment: find gives only one element what if there is more than one. BTW i didn't mean downvoting, I just wanted revoke my upvote :)

Comment: Could you please duplicate the first element of the `array` and try. I downvote you downvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Change with this:

```
array.filter(x => filter.every( a => x.someOtherProps.includes(a)));
```

Comment: I do not need an explanation I guess